# Adding multiple hidden layers keras

Tags: python-3.x, keras, nlp, deep-learning, sentiment-analysis

I have a simple sentiment analyzer using keras, here is my code, in which I use the keras code on github: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/imdb_lstm.py

The initial and working model is:

```
from __future__ import print_function

from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Embedding, Activation
from keras.layers import GRU, LeakyReLU
from keras.datasets import imdb

max_features = 2000
maxlen = 80  # cut texts after this number of words (among top max_features most common words)
batch_size = 256
hidden_layer_size = 32
dropout = 0.2
num_epochs = 1
activation_func = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.5)

print('Loading data...')
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=max_features)
print(len(x_train), 'train sequences')
print(len(x_test), 'test sequences')

print('Pad sequences (samples x time)')
x_train = sequence.pad_sequences(x_train, maxlen=maxlen)
x_test = sequence.pad_sequences(x_test, maxlen=maxlen)
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print('x_test shape:', x_test.shape)

print('Build model...')
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, hidden_layer_size))
model.add(GRU(hidden_layer_size, dropout=dropout, recurrent_dropout=dropout))
model.add(Activation(activation_func))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# try using different optimizers and different optimizer configs
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

print('Train...')
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=num_epochs,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
score, acc = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test,
                            batch_size=batch_size)
print('Test score:', score)
print('Test accuracy:', acc)
```

The error I get is this one:

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer gru_2: expected ndim=3,
>   found ndim=2

This happens every time I try to add a second hidden layer on the model, for instance:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, hidden_layer_size))
model.add(GRU(hidden_layer_size, dropout=dropout, recurrent_dropout=dropout))
model.add(Activation(activation_func))
model.add(GRU(hidden_layer_size, dropout=dropout, recurrent_dropout=dropout))
model.add(Activation(activation_func))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

I believe I am missing something concerning the dimensions of the hidden layers. How should I proceed to add another hidden layer successfully?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because by default the RNN layers in Keras *only return the last output*, i.e. an input `(samples, time_steps, features)` becomes `(samples, hidden_layer_size)`. In order to chain multiple RNNs you need to set the hidden RNN layers to have `return_sequences=True`:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, hidden_layer_size))
# Add return_sequences=True
model.add(GRU(hidden_layer_size, activation=activation_func, dropout=dropout, recurrent_dropout=dropout, return_sequences=True))
# (samples, time_steps, hidden_layer_size)
model.add(GRU(hidden_layer_size, activation=activation_func, dropout=dropout, recurrent_dropout=dropout))
# (samples, hidden_layer_size)
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

You can also return the last hidden etc, have a look at the [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/) on what these parameters do.